# What makes the nervous and anxious character model of Michael Cera, Jesse Eisenerg etc... so successful?

Tags: character

Although these two specific actors are gradually becoming more confident in the roles that they portray, what is it specifically about the 'stereotypical young adult without any confidence' that we relate to so well? Why do we view these kinds of characters as non-masculine yet identify with them and love them so much?

i.e Cera in Youth In Revolt,Juno,Superbad etc... Eisenberg in Adventureland,Social Network, Zombieland etc..

Comment: Woody Allen is probably the origin of this specific type of modern character in cinema.  It is most evident in his early films, but he certainly continued to play this role until people stopped wanting to see him on film.  You will note that Jesse Eisenberg actually played the "Allen role" in his recent film Cafe Society, although Allen has also cast as widely as Will Ferell (Melinda & Melinda), Owen Wilson (Midnight in Paris) and Kenneth Branagh (Celebrity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one aspect of what is called the Anti-Hero.

In Juno, he's just a "normal guy" and, potentially chosen because he is not someone people expect a fictional teenage girl in a movie would fantasize about. Also, they were going for a semblance of reality here rather than some weird hyper-perfect version we often see in a teenage movie.

In action movies the anti-hero is quickly relatable, makes the danger seem even more dangerous.

The anti-hero has a potential for growth, which is crucial for building a character. It is tiresome to see the perfect person become even more perfectly perfecter.

As far as identifying with them etc. that's in the casting, writing and delivery. I am certain you can find more examples of failure in this regard.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihero .  That about sums it up.

Comment: @Yorik Interesting concept, thanks! I wonder to what extent Cera's character in Juno was molded to fit his actual persona and style, or whether he simply placed himself into the finished version of the character.

Comment: These characters are anything but anti-hero.